# vnc4Server Issue

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, amazon-ec2

I initially installed VNC4SERVER to run Guacamole (render VM through browser) on an AWS EC2 Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) instance. It worked fine and then I shutdown the instance. After a few days I started it again, and then I noticed VNC not working properly.

I went into terminal and checked it out, and here were the logs:

```
  GNU nano 2.2.6                               File: /root/.vnc/ip-10-148-67-7:2.log                                                                    

04/06/13 17:28:46 Xvnc version TightVNC-1.3.9
04/06/13 17:28:46 Copyright (C) 2000-2007 TightVNC Group
04/06/13 17:28:46 Copyright (C) 1999 AT&T Laboratories Cambridge
04/06/13 17:28:46 All Rights Reserved.
04/06/13 17:28:46 See http://www.tightvnc.com/ for information on TightVNC
04/06/13 17:28:46 Desktop name 'X' (ip-10-148-67-7:2)
04/06/13 17:28:46 Protocol versions supported: 3.3, 3.7, 3.8, 3.7t, 3.8t
04/06/13 17:28:46 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 5902
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/' not found - ignoring
Font directory '/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/' not found - ignoring
No VNC extension on display :2
gnome-session[3440]: WARNING: GSIdleMonitor: IDLETIME counter not found
gnome-session-is-accelerated: No composite extension.
gnome-session-check-accelerated: Helper exited with code 256
gnome-session[3440]: WARNING: Session 'gnome-classic' runnable check failed: Exited with code 1
GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL=/tmp/keyring-Qol7F5
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/keyring-Qol7F5/gpg:0:1
GNOME_KEYRING_PID=3458
```

Can anyone help? Any piece of information or advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: These logs do not give much clue to me. can you try to restart your session see if that works ?

Comment: define restart session. I've killed vncserver (vncserver -kill :1 or any number) many times and started it again and again. The logs all say the same thing, the same as above.

Comment: Yes, I meant the same. `vncserver -kill :1` what error message do you get on the viewer side? can you enable debug log by run the vnc server and viewer with -Log flag like  `vncserver -Log=*:stderr:100  ` and `vncviwer -Log=*:stderr:100`